# How to remove Card View from Recycler View, from a separate Activity

Tags: java, android

Here's the situation:

I am trying to remove a users information from an ArrayList(populated via Firebase Database) on a Card View.

This Card View is populated in the Recycler View. When the user clicks on a Card in the Recycler view, they are brought to a detail activity via an Intent.

In the intent, there is more user data as well as the option to approve or reject the user.

I want to be able to reject the user and then remove their card from the Recycler View.

I keep running into a null pointer error and I am not sure where else to go.

Stack trace is at the end.

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Relevant code below:

Fragment:

```
package org.codefordenver.encorelink;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;

public class OrganizerDashboardPendingTab extends Fragment {


    private String userId;


    //Arraylist to hold our list of volunteer musicians
    public static ArrayList<String> volunteerSmallView = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<String>  volunteerDetail = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<String> volunteerLink = new ArrayList<>();

    //private String field members to hold temp String data
    private String tempFirst;
    private String tempTalent;
    private String tempLastName;
    private String tempPhoneNumber;
    private String tempStreetAddress;
    private String tempCity;
    private String tempZipcode;
    public static String tempVideoLink;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        final RecyclerView musicianInfoRecycler = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);


        //Checking to make sure user is logged in and is not null
        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            userId = user.getUid();
        }
        //setting DatabaseReference variable so we can search through the correct node in our DB
        DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(CreateMusicianProfile.MUSICIAN_PROFILE);

        //Instantiating and declaring our Adapter object for our Recycler View
        final PendingMusicianInfoAdapter adapter = new PendingMusicianInfoAdapter(volunteerSmallView);

        //this clear is a must so we aren't getting duplicated data in the cardview
        volunteerSmallView.clear();
        //Adding child event listener to our database object
        mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                //iterate through each dataSnapshot inside mDatabase
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    //if we get a first name, add it to temp string
                    if (dataSnapshot1.getKey().equals("firstName")) {
                        tempFirst = Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot1.getValue(String.class));
                    }

                    if (dataSnapshot1.getKey().equals("lastName")) {
                        tempLastName = Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot1.getValue(String.class));
                    }

                    //if we get a musical talent, save it also into a temp string
                    if (dataSnapshot1.getKey().equals("musicalTalent")) {
                        tempTalent = Objects.requireNonNull("\nTalent: " + dataSnapshot1.getValue(String.class));

                        //in order to display all the string data together in one card,
                        //we have to add each temp string to the array list.

                            volunteerSmallView.add(tempFirst + " " + tempLastName + tempTalent);

                    }

                    if (dataSnapshot1.getKey().equals("phoneNumber")) {
                        tempPhoneNumber = Objects.requireNonNull( dataSnapshot1.getValue(String.class));
                    }

                    if (dataSnapshot1.getKey().equals("streetAddress")) {
                        tempStreetAddress = Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot1.getValue(String.class));
                    }

                    if (dataSnapshot1.getKey().equals("city")) {
                        tempCity = Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot1.getValue(String.class));
                    }

                    if (dataSnapshot1.getKey().equals("zipcode")) {
                        tempZipcode = Objects.requireNonNull("Zipcode: " + dataSnapshot1.getValue(String.class));
                    }

                    if (dataSnapshot1.getKey().equals("videoLink")) {
                        tempVideoLink = Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot1.getValue(String.class));
                        volunteerLink.add(tempVideoLink);

                        volunteerDetail.add(tempFirst + " " + tempLastName +
                                "\n" + tempPhoneNumber +
                                "\n" + tempStreetAddress +
                                "\n" + tempCity + ", " + tempZipcode + "\n" + tempTalent + "\n");

                    }

                }
                //set adapater equal to our adapater object
                musicianInfoRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        musicianInfoRecycler.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        adapter.setListener(new PendingMusicianInfoAdapter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MusicianDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra(MusicianDetails.EXTRA_NUMBER, position);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        return musicianInfoRecycler;

    }

}
```

RecyclerView Adapter:

This class contains the rejectionButton and the onClickListener but it is always pointing to null.

```
package org.codefordenver.encorelink;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PendingMusicianInfoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PendingMusicianInfoAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> musicianInfo;
    private Listener listener;


    public interface Listener {
        void onClick(int position);
    }

    public void setListener(Listener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private CardView cardView;
        Button rejectionButton;


        public ViewHolder(CardView view) {
            super(view);
            cardView = view;
            rejectionButton =  view.findViewById(R.id.musician_rejection);


            rejectionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try {
                            removeAt(getAdapterPosition());
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });




        }

        void bind(final int position) {

            TextView textView = cardView.findViewById(R.id.pending_musician_info);
            textView.setText(musicianInfo.get(position));
            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onClick(position);
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        void removeAt(int position) {
            musicianInfo.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, musicianInfo.size());
        }

    }

    public PendingMusicianInfoAdapter(ArrayList<String> musicianInfo) {
        this.musicianInfo = musicianInfo;
    }


    //called when recyclerview instantiates new viewholder instance
    //creates the views
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


        CardView cv = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_musician_info, parent, false);


        return new ViewHolder(cv);
    }

    //called when recycler view wants to populate data from model for the user to see
    //after each view holder is created, recycler view calls onBindViewHolder to populate item
    //with data
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(position);


    }


    //returns number of items in data source
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return musicianInfo.size();
    }
}
```

Musician Details class that is triggered from the OrganizerDashboardPendingTab class.

```
package org.codefordenver.encorelink;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class MusicianDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_NUMBER = "number";
//
//    public static ArrayList<String> approvedMusicians = new ArrayList<>();
    private TextView closeButton;
    public static int cardNumber;
    private String talentURL;
    private TextView musicalTalentLink;
    private Button approvalButton;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private String userId;
    public static boolean approved;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_musician_details);

        closeButton = findViewById(R.id.x_button);
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.musician_details);
        musicalTalentLink = findViewById(R.id.musical_talent_link);

        approvalButton = findViewById(R.id.musician_approval);


        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            userId = user.getUid();
        }




        cardNumber = (int) Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).get(EXTRA_NUMBER);
        String musicianDetails = OrganizerDashboardPendingTab.volunteerDetail.get(cardNumber);

        findURL(OrganizerDashboardPendingTab.volunteerLink);
        musicalTalentLink.setText(talentURL);
        textView.setText(musicianDetails);

        musicalTalentLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(talentURL));
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
                    Toast.makeText(MusicianDetails.this, "Bad URL!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        approvalButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                approvedMusicians.add(OrganizerDashboardPendingTab.volunteerDetail.get(cardNumber));
                databaseReference.child(CreateOrganizerProfile.ORGANIZER_PROFILE).child(userId).child("approved_musicians").child(String.valueOf(cardNumber)).
                        setValue(OrganizerDashboardPendingTab.volunteerDetail.get(cardNumber));
                Toast.makeText(MusicianDetails.this, "Musician approved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT - 3).show();
                Toast.makeText(MusicianDetails.this, "Moving musician to In Progress...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                approved = true;


            }
        });



        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    public void findURL(ArrayList<String> data) {

        Matcher m = Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(data.get (cardNumber));
        while (m.find()) {
            String url = m.group();
            talentURL = url;
        }
    }




}
```

card_musician_info.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/musician_info_cardview"
    card_view:cardElevation="3.5sp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pending_musician_info"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />





    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: org.codefordenver.encorelink, PID: 12123
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                      at org.codefordenver.encorelink.PendingMusicianInfoAdapter$ViewHolder.<init>(PendingMusicianInfoAdapter.java:41)
                      at org.codefordenver.encorelink.PendingMusicianInfoAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(PendingMusicianInfoAdapter.java:94)
                      at org.codefordenver.encorelink.PendingMusicianInfoAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(PendingMusicianInfoAdapter.java:16)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6493)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5680)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3962)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1767)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
                      at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:132)
                      at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                      at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:869)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:761)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2496)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2212)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: One of your button is not initialized correctly and return null. Check `rejectionButton`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PendingMusicianInfoAdapter you are using:-

*rejectionButton* =  view.findViewById(R.id.musician_rejection); **//here is your null pointer**

**Reason:-**

In you card_musician_info.xml
you **don't have any Button "musician_rejection"**

**NOTE**:- Every time you face any null pointer issue it is most commonly due to wrong initialization/ id mismatch / or no reference in correct XML.
In this case, you may have "musician_rejection" earlier which was registered in your "R" class but later you may have removed it but in your "R" class it somehow stays. Or it can be quite possible that you may have  "musician_rejection"  in some other XML. Android Studio is not that smart enough to understand that use parent XML file for all its id references in JAVA file.

**Use http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/ which eliminates all such issues.**

Use debugger step by step, For better understanding.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I will check out butterknife tomorrow. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this situation you need to use EventBus.
Try https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus